# How to make the Gitversion VSTS increment release number on master?

Tags: azure-pipelines, gitversion

I have configured my git repository in VSTS with the GitFlow repository.

I have a master branch with a dotnet core project, and a release branch called 'Release/1.0.0'. When I create a pull-request and merge the release/1.0.0 branch back to master, it does not increment it's version number to 1.0.0. Instead, it's increasing the version number from 0.1.0 (the base fallback) to 0.1.1.

Build log:

```
Calculating base versions
Fallback base version: 0.1.0 with commit count source xx
Git tag '0.1.0': 0.1.0 with commit count source xx
Base version used: Git tag '0.1.0': 0.1.0 with commit count source xx
```

However, the commit label is Merge branch Release/1.0.0 to master. And the branch being merged is tagged as 1.0.0.

I am using GitVersion default settings. I am using the GitVersion VSTS task.

This is the gitversion configuration:

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDelivery
branches: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
```

What should i do to automatically set the version of the master branch to the versionnumber that is being merged?

Update:
I found out what was going "wrong".

Releases were merged back as pull requests. This will set the commit message to Merge PR #### . However, the MergeMessageBaseVersionStrategy of gitversion can not handle this. If i merge the release back as a regular merge, the version number is increased.

Comment: Does the build is triggered for PR validation? And can you should the GitVersion.yml file and the setting for GitVersion task in your build definition?

Comment: The master branch has a policy that code can only be added after completing a PR. After completion the build is triggered. I added the gitversion configuration

Comment: You can remove generated "Merged PR..." prefix before completing pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the GitVersion task in the CI build for `master` branch (or queue build after the PR is completed) instead of PR build validation.

Since the PR build validation is triggered **before** `release/1.0.0` branch really merge into `master`, so Gitversion will detect the version from `master` branch (such as version in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file).

If you add the GitVersion task in CI build (**after** the `release/1.0.0` branch merged into `master` branch), then Gitversion will detect the version major.minor.patch=1.0.0 from `release/1.0.0` branch.